# getting user input and altering it in java

Tags: java

I am asked to get user input for a membership type.

memberships being Gold/Silver/Bronze.

```
Gold membership = 750
Silver membership = 450
Bronze membership = 250
```

The next step is to ask the user if he requires snow tyre hire, if so it's an additional 10 percent, however I was stuck at that point, is there a way to get the result of the membership input by the user and use an if statement to determine whether or not to add 10 percent.

Here's the code i have so far.

```
import java.io.*;
public class SkiLodge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        InputStreamReader ui = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader gd = new BufferedReader(ui);
        BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(ui);
        BufferedReader bz = new BufferedReader(ui);

        System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze");
        String membership = gd.readLine();

        double x;

        if (membership.equals("Gold"))
            System.out.println("Gold Membership Selected: £" + (x = 750));
        else if (membership.equals("Silver"))
            System.out.println("Silver Membership Selected: £" + (x = 450));
        else if (membership.equals("Bronze"))
            System.out.println("Bronze Membership Selected: £" + (x = 250));
        else System.out.println("Invalid Membership");



        System.out.println("Do you require snow tyre rental? (yes/no)");
        String tyreRental = sr.readLine();


        if (tyreRental.equals("yes"))   
            System.out.println(x = x * 1.1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only create one `Reader` and use that to read all input. Since they all origin from the `System.in` your input will be in all the readers. For example, the input for "Gold/Silver/Bronze" will be in everyone of your `BufferedReader`'s so when you read the `String tyreRental = sr.readLine();` you will actually read the "Gold/Silver/Bronze" input again.

This should be working better for you:

```
import java.io.*;
public class SkiLodge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        InputStreamReader ui = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(ui);

        System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze");
        String membership = inputReader.readLine();

        double x = 0.0d;

        if (membership.equals("Gold"))
            System.out.println("Gold Membership Selected: £" + (x = 750));
        else if (membership.equals("Silver"))
            System.out.println("Silver Membership Selected: £" + (x = 450));
        else if (membership.equals("Bronze"))
            System.out.println("Bronze Membership Selected: £" + (x = 250));
        else System.out.println("Invalid Membership");



        System.out.println("Do you require snow tyre rental? (yes/no)");
        String tyreRental = inputReader.readLine();


        if (tyreRental.equals("yes"))
            System.out.println(x = x * 1.1);

    }

}
```

Comment: It still gives the same error "The local variable x may not have been initialized"

Comment: Ok, just initialize it to `0.0` when you declare it. I will update the answer.

Comment: Cool, if you think this answer you question fully you can accept the answer also :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. :)

```
import java.io.*;
public class SkiLodge {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    InputStreamReader ui = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader gd = new BufferedReader(ui);
    BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(ui);
    BufferedReader bz = new BufferedReader(ui);

    System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze");
    String membership = gd.readLine();

    double x = 0.0;
    double a = 0.0;
    if (membership.equals("Gold"))
        System.out.println("Gold Membership Selected: £" + (x = 750));
    else if (membership.equals("Silver"))
        System.out.println("Silver Membership Selected: £" + (x = 450));
    else if (membership.equals("Bronze"))
        System.out.println("Bronze Membership Selected: £" + (x = 250));
    else System.out.println("Invalid Membership");


    System.out.println("Do you require snow tyre rental? (yes/no)");
    String tyreRental = sr.readLine();

    x = x * 1.1;
    a = x;
    if (tyreRental.equals("yes"))   
        System.out.println(a);

}
}
```